# How to design the range and precision of a radar?

Tags: radio, waves, radar

I would like to design the wave characteristics and size of antenna for a radar, but I am quite confused about how to find this information.

The radar should have roughly following capabilities:

- Range: up to 5 miles
- Precision: objects of 0.5m to 5 m size (I know that RCS is an issue there, but I will suppose here a square of 0.5m*05m)
- Doppler capability

And I suppose the information I need to design the radar are:

- Wavelength
- Frequency of pulse
- Antenna length
- Voltage power to apply on the antenna

Comment: You should also specify somehow how reflective is the target material, how it moves (=to make some separation from clutter echoes from the ground), which radio frequency range with how high allowed radiation intensity (avg and max peak) you have succeeded to purchase for your usage, how fast you expect the detection to happen with what probability etc,etc,etc.... I'm afraid you would do better by getting a radar design book.

Comment: @user287001 I understand the two first points. However what do you mean with radio frequency and peak? I have not purchase any device yet.

Comment: You shouldn't build nor purchase a device which calls the police as soon as you use it. Radio frequency space is a strictly regulated resource in all countries on the Earth. If you happen to be the son or brother of the local dictator you may have some freedom, but the rest of us must stay in the frequency band we have license for and  keep our devices so quiet that no specified limit is exceeded. There are many limits, power is only one of them.